# Debugging multiple Node js Function apps in VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger

I am currently developing a couple of node js function apps in the same project that I would like to be able to debug together. After some effort I was able to run them without a debugger with compounds. And it kinda works since all functions are running although im only able to see output from one at a time.

```
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Func1",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: start - func1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Func2",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: start - func2"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Compound",
            "configurations": [
                "Func1",
                "Func2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start",
            "path": "func1/",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: start - func1",
            "detail": "func start"
        },
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "start",
            "path": "func2/",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: start - func2",
            "detail": "func start"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also tried different configurations in tasks.json and launch.json using func start with moderate success and I have been able to attach a single function app to debugger while starting the rest.

```
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: start - func1"
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-node-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "dependsOn": "npm: install - func1",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/func1"
            }
```

But when I attempt to add a second one with another label it is only able to recognize one of them and the launch of the other app receives error "Could not find the task 'func: start - func2'".

My questions are if it is possible to have multiple Function App attached to debugger and in that case how? Would it also be possible to get the logs in the same output terminal or multiple terminals for each Function App. I know that both can be achived in Visual Studio with c# but is it possible in VS Code with Node.

Answer (score 0):

> I am currently developing a couple of node js function apps in the
> same project

1, If your function app here refers to Trigger, then the default settings of VS Code should be able to be achieved (unprocessed functions will be in a waiting state, but every place marked with a breakpoint will be executed, but you cannot be in different at the same time Breakpoints).

2, If your function app here refers to a standalone app, then the key is the port. Below settings can change the default port of function app on local:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 5861,
    "CORS": "*",
    "CORSCredentials": false
  }
}
```

After the above settings, you can start two VS Code programs Debug different function app at the same time without causing conflicts.